# Rails paperclip and update_attributes for model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

As I see in logs, when I update_attributes for model that have attachment, no matter what attribute I refresh, it is always full entry refreshed - for example:

I have model User which have fields:

```
-active
-photo ( with :thumb, :large, :org etc. styles for paperclip)
```

When I made @user.update_attributes(:active => true), it takes very long time because (as I see in logs) photo is refreshed by paperclip and all attachment are recreated.

Is it normal behavior or I have some bug ?

This is log for update for model with ID:

Comment: Do you have any other ActiveRecord callbacks on the User model?

Comment: no it's only one field update

Comment: OK I KNOW, i made before_save ...